# Throwing http 400 for missing Query param and query param with # character

Tags: rest, http-status-code-400

I have built a rest api and I am facing a problem to tackle the invalid requests.

I need to throw HTTP 400 BAD request in the http response, for the following requests:

```
orders/{orders}/order_file.{format}
```

This is the uri that I am using.

If clients key in the url as `orders//order_file.json` I should be able to throw http 400 error.

If clients key in the url as `orders/234#/order_file.json` I should be able to throw the same http 400 error.

Instead The control is not getting inside the uri handlers for the above 2 scenarios.

Comment: What do you use as the server technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path

```
orders//order_file.json
```

is probably interpreted as

```
orders/order_file.json
```

If you have no rule to match such a path, you will get a `404 Not Found`.

The path

```
orders/234#/order_file.json
```

has a real path `orders/234` and a fragment `/order_file.json`. Again, if you don't have a rule that matches `orders/234`, you will get a `404 Not Found`.

Comment: I am using tomcat server, i have implemented REST using jersey 2.* You were right about the first one. orders//abcd is taken as orders/abcd

Comment: what uri do you propose to handle the second one. thanks a lot for the solution !!

Comment: The second URL already is handled correctly by a `404 Not Found`. What user enters `234#` as a *path* segment? For such users `404` is fine, `400` would not be any better.

Comment: got it man !! orders/234#/abcd is taken as orders/234. God bless you